# How to create a multi-level document with limited levels in Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013

I have a document which has 5 headings deep. I've converted the headings to multi-level numbered headings, but I only want the numbering to go 4 levels deep not to levels 5 and 6.

I can't find anywhere to do that.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want a numbering system limited to the levels 1 to 4.

1. From the `Ribbon > Home` and grouped above `Paragrph`, click the button `Multilevel List`. From the popup menu, choose `Define New Multilevel List`.

[image: ml]

Note: The dialogue box may look smaller than the above screenshot because I expanded it.

2. On the left, choose the level to be excluded from the numbering. In your case, start with the level 5.
3. On the field `Enter formatting for number` and erase the number.
4. Repeat step 2 and 3 with the other levels.